# RestSharp returns IRestResponse.StatusCode == 0 to Polly onRetry

Tags: c#, restsharp, polly

I wrote a fairly simple wrapper around the RestSharp client adding some retry logic to it using Polly.
I setup Fiddler to test it and simulated some "Bad" responses.

The problem I have is in the onRetry delegate, the `result.Result.StatusCode` bit seems to sometimes log as 0 instead of the actual bad status code (502 in some of my testings).

However, with my unit tests it seems that its working perfectly. Race conditions here maybe?

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Polly;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

namespace FundsAFE.Graphite
{
    public class RequestExecutor
    {
        private static readonly NLog.Logger logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private IRestClient client;
        private IRestRequest request;
        private Policy<IRestResponse> retryPolicy;

        public IRestResponse LastErrorResponse { get; set; }

        private static readonly List<HttpStatusCode> invalidStatusCodes = new List<HttpStatusCode> {
            HttpStatusCode.BadGateway,
            HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,
            HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout,
            HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
            HttpStatusCode.Forbidden,
            HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout
        };


        public RequestExecutor(IRestClient client, IRestRequest request)
        {
            this.client = client;
            this.request = request;
        }

        public IRestResponse Execute(int retryCount, int delay)
        {

            retryPolicy = Policy                
                .HandleResult<IRestResponse>(resp => invalidStatusCodes.Contains(resp.StatusCode) || !IsValidJson(resp))                
                .WaitAndRetry(retryCount, i => TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(delay), (result, timeSpan, currentRetryCount, context) =>
                {
                    //Status code here is sometimes 0???
                    logger.Error($"Request failed with {result.Result.StatusCode}. Waiting {timeSpan} before next retry. Retry attempt {currentRetryCount}");
                    LastErrorResponse = result.Result;
                });

            var policyResponse = retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture(() =>
            {
                var url = client.BuildUri(request);
                logger.Debug(url.ToString());
                var response = client.Execute(request);
                return response;
            });
            if(policyResponse.Result != null)
            {
                return policyResponse.Result;
            } else
            {
                return LastErrorResponse;
            }
        }

        public static bool IsValidJson(IRestResponse response)
        {
            if (response.Content.Length == 0)
            {
                //Empty response treated as invalid
                return false;
            }
            try
            {
                var parsed = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException e)
            {
                //Will catch any mallformed json
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}


using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using FundsAFE.Graphite;
using Moq;
using RestSharp;
using System.Net;
using FluentAssertions;
using System;
using FluentAssertions.Extensions;

namespace FundsAFE.Test.Moq
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MoqUnitTestRequest
    {

        public Mock<IRestClient> CreateMockClientWithStatusCodeAndContent(HttpStatusCode code, string content)
        {
            Mock<IRestClient> mockClient = new Mock<IRestClient>();
            mockClient.Setup(c => c.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>())).Returns(
                new RestResponse
                {
                    Content = content,
                    StatusCode = code
                }
            );

            mockClient.Setup(c => c.BuildUri(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>())).Returns(
                new Uri("http://fake.fake")
            );

            return mockClient;
        }

        [DataTestMethod]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.BadGateway)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.RequestTimeout)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)]
        [DataRow(HttpStatusCode.GatewayTimeout)]
        public void TestBadStatusCodesAndRetry(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode) {
            //Arrange
            Mock<IRestRequest> mockRequest = new Mock<IRestRequest>();
            Mock<IRestClient> mockClient = CreateMockClientWithStatusCodeAndContent(httpStatusCode, "fakecontent");
            RequestExecutor requestExecutor = new RequestExecutor(mockClient.Object, mockRequest.Object);

            int retries = 10;
            int delay = 50;
            int totalWaitTime = (retries * delay) - 10; //10ms error margin

            //Act and Verify            
            var response = requestExecutor.Execute(retryCount: retries, delay: 101);
            mockClient.Verify(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()), Times.Exactly(retries + 1)); //1st failed attempt + 10 retries = 11            

            //Assert            
            requestExecutor.ExecutionTimeOf(re => re.Execute(retries, delay)).Should().BeGreaterOrEqualTo(totalWaitTime.Milliseconds());
            response.Should().NotBeNull();
            response.StatusCode.Should().Be(httpStatusCode);
            requestExecutor.LastErrorResponse.StatusCode.Should().Be(httpStatusCode);
        }

        [DataTestMethod]
        //Empty content
        [DataRow("")]
        //Missing closing quote
        [DataRow("{\"fruit\": \"Apple,\"size\": \"Large\",\"color\": \"Red\"}")]
        //Missing angle bracket
        [DataRow("\"q1\": {\"question\": \"Which one is correct team name in NBA?\",\"options\": \"New York Bulls\",\"Los Angeles Kings\",\"Golden State Warriros\",\"Huston Rocket\"],\"answer\": \"Huston Rocket\"}")]
        //Missing curly bracket
        [DataRow("\"sport\": {\"q1\": {\"question\": \"Which one is correct team name in NBA?\",\"options\": \"New York Bulls\",\"Los Angeles Kings\",\"Golden State Warriros\",\"Huston Rocket\"],\"answer\": \"Huston Rocket\"}")]
        public void TestBadContentRetries(string content)
        {

            //Arrange
            Mock<IRestRequest> mockRequest = new Mock<IRestRequest>();
            Mock<IRestClient> mockClient = CreateMockClientWithStatusCodeAndContent(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
            RequestExecutor requestExecutor = new RequestExecutor(mockClient.Object, mockRequest.Object);

            int retries = 10;
            int delay = 50;
            int totalWaitTime = (retries * delay) - 10; //10ms error margin

            //Act and Verify            
            var response = requestExecutor.Execute(retryCount: retries, delay: delay);
            mockClient.Verify(x => x.Execute(It.IsAny<IRestRequest>()), Times.Exactly(retries + 1)); //1st failed attempt + 10 retries = 11            

            //Assert            
            requestExecutor.ExecutionTimeOf(re => re.Execute(retries, delay)).Should().BeGreaterOrEqualTo(totalWaitTime.Milliseconds());
            response.Should().NotBeNull();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks from the RESTsharp source code as if there are cases (eg [some exception cases](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/42f086a895ae3cb8c295557086eba0d3fb1df22c/RestSharp/Http.Sync.cs#L125-L140)) where RESTsharp might well return you an `IRestResponse` with `resp.StatusCode == 0`.  The logging code in `onRetry` should probably be checking the [wider set of status properties on `IRestResponse`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IHttpResponse.cs#L67-L81), not just `IRestResponse.StatusCode` . (If this is what's happening, I can write it up as full answer.)

Comment: Let me explorer this. Ill get back to you

Answer (score 1):

It looks from the RESTsharp source code as if there are cases (eg [some exception cases](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/42f086a895ae3cb8c295557086eba0d3fb1df22c/RestSharp/Http.Sync.cs#L125-L140)) where RESTsharp might well return you an `IRestResponse` with `resp.StatusCode == 0`.

The logging code in `onRetry` should probably be checking the [wider set of status properties on `IRestResponse`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/IHttpResponse.cs#L67-L81), not just `IRestResponse.StatusCode`